# Need help beating Spice Bandits level Wooden Walls

Tags: spice-bandits

I've tried and tried, replayed earlier levels over to level up, nothing I do is working.  Can anyone help me with a strategy for Wooden Walls - the third level in Africa?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming SE Cat!  To help us help you, can you provide some more details?  For example, what have you tried doing?  What specific parts of the game are you struggling with?  Be as specific as possible in order to ensure a great answer.

Answer (score 5):

Build some level 3 Tesla Coils where the creeps come, and it will defend you for a few early air waves too. That will help save money. Then build the air towers, and build some fart and goo towers to defend the ground waves, and if you have enough money building nukes will help too.

I did it with these conditions:

```
massive builder   10
frequent upgrader 10
damage            10
```

Comment: Thank you thank you! I followed your upgrades and Tesla coils, played a few more times and DONE!

Answer (score 0):

It is a hard level but I passed it by using a ton of magic abilities like freeze and auto defence. I used mainly tesla coils.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a corridor near the base? I line up five towers in a line, south to north, then another line of four towers one space to the left, north to south, and a final line of two or three, as much as I can afford.  With upgrade points, I'm putting out 13 towers at start.  As you can, upgrade to the best mini guns, add some slow towers by round 10 or so, and get your AA when needed.  Any time I have trouble with a level, it usually means I need to upgrade more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [the other answer about building Tesla coils](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/51358/3389) near the enemy entrance as a start, that helped me. I don't have all the upgrades listed, here are mine:

- Damage 7/10
- M Builder 8/10
- F Upgrader 7/10

I managed to complete the level anyway even though my base was quite severely damaged in the process.

After the 3 Tesla coils, I built a goo gun to slow down the creeps, and then I had to build another Tesla coil (and later some missiles) near my base as some fast running creeps broke through anyway. I just used missiles and an AA gun to pass the level with the aircraft. I did *not* have to use any magic, and actually managed to pass the level.

As I got more money, I upgraded a few of my Tesla coils near the top left to BBQs as well as the one beside my base.

Answer (score -1):

I cleaned it with building a route to next to base with teslas and some air defense.

Comment: Please see the comment attached to Henry's answer.  For this type of question it's best to explain _why_ your solution is good, as well as possibly some pros/cons compared to other solutions.