# How do you do the Walls level?

Tags: spice-bandits

I have tried and tried and tried, but always die. I've got the towers up too: sniper minigun 1, super minigun 2, f.a.r.t tower 2, power gateway 1, AA gun 3, buff tower 1, baby nuke, and Katayusha. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah i also have baby nuke, katyusha

Comment: When you have new information to add to your question you can edit the question directly, you do not have to put it into the comments :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Need help beating Spice Bandits level Wooden Walls](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/51325/21177)

Answer (score 1):

Block the 3 single isleways with long range snipers so the enemy cant pass and set up a tower in the larger isleway center at the entry in the V formed by the wrecked red cars.

[image]

This way, all of the ground forces have to pass it. Then raise it to BBQ as your snipers earn money. As you earn, add an aircraft gun in the middle-rear by the HEY bus even with the E.

Raise it to the highest sniper level. With it and 3 ground snipers, the aircraft can't last. Add another tower 5 spaces forward of the first BBQ and raise it up to BBQ too.

At some point in there, add a launcher in the rear near the H in the HEY bus because a couple enemies can get to it. Now upgrade Matryoshka. Then, add a megaphone in the middle of them and increase it to highest radar level.

You now have the level in your grasp. Burn it up!

Comment: Thnx helps alot